# font-awesome not working with Apache 2.4.x

Tags: apache, font-awesome

When I try to statically use font-awesome (fa) in my project with Apache 2.4.x the icons will not show up. Fa works with apache 2.2.x, and Python's SimpleHHTPServer.

This is not the IE/Firefox issue where a box is displayed instead of the icon.

I am using this in Dreamfactory (OSX), but I have also tried vanilla Apache from MacPorts with the same results.

Chrome's console reports the following when the page loads:

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/troff: `"http://localhost:8080/files/applications/CADRe/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css".`

Fa was installed with bower and I am including it like this:

```
<link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My project also includes angularjs and bootstrap.

Comment: Are you running DreamFactory via Bitnami?  Using Grunt to minify/concat/etc before running?

Comment: I am using DreamFactory locally on OSX Mavericks.  I am not using Grunt.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the DreamFactory admin console, do you see icons?  Those use the Bootstrap CDN to serve up font awesome.

This could be an apache config issue , in which case you'd need to edit your apache config to support the mime type:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/truetype ttf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
```

I would put this as a comment, but this is a new account, and I'm disallowed.

Comment: I do see icons in dreamfactory, but not in my app within dreamfactory.  I tried adding the code above to the bottom of dreamfactory's httpd.conf file, but then I also noticed they were uncommented in mime.types.

Comment: Not an apache or dreamfactory issue then i'm afraid.  We use font awesome in the Angular Todo app that came pre-installed on your DSP as well.  Try using the CDN first to verify your min file isn't either corrupt or being misinterpreted .

Comment: The CDN works fine. I guess I'll just use that until I figure out why the local files don't work.

Comment: I can still look into this, did you use the Bitnami installer?

Comment: Yes, I used the Bitnami installer.

Answer (score 0):

Add css with full path and above provided add font mytype in either .htaccess or apachec config file

```
<link href="http://localhost:8080/files/applications/CADRe/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**In .htaccess**

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/truetype ttf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
```