# Fontawesome not working on apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, font-awesome

I have built a Wordpress site which I originally hosted on IIS.
I then moved the site to a Linux server on which I setup Apache and MariaDB.
An annoyance though is that I can't get fontawesome to work for the site when it runs on the apache server. It worked fine on IIS.
I am using the Vantage theme which has some of fontawesome's icons built in.
Since they wont work after I moved the website, i also tried to download the fontawesome.css and host it locally, then update the code to load the icons from there - but it still wont work.
I also tried to load the fontawesome css from CDN instead of a local file, but that didnt work either.
Finally, I also tried to make sure the following was enabled in the servers  mimetypes file:
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
    font/truetype ttf
    application/x-font-woff woff

And I also tried to add the following to .htaccess:
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
    AddType font/truetype ttf
    AddType application/x-font-woff woff

All according to suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721799/font-awesome-not-working-with-apache-2-4-x).

I asked my friend Google, but he came up with no further leads, so I'm kind of out of ideas. Any suggestions?

PS.
I have setup the server configuration myself, so I'm not using any hosting service for the website.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment as I don't have enough rep, but have you imported the font in your css? e.g. @import /path/to/font/awesome and done all the usual stuff like specify the font-face/type? Sorry if this is no help at all.

TL;DR: there should be no reason why you can't download the font-awesome files and put them within your websites' folder and reference to it like any normal resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have not made an import of the file in my .css, just added a <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://my-url/font-awesome.min.css"> to my header.php file. I will try an import as well.

Comment: Added the @import to my style.css but it still did not work. Verified that the url to the font-awesome.min.css is correct both for the css import and for the header link url.

Comment: This is super weird. But I just solved it. How?
I removed the <a href> tag around the h1 element which preceeded the fontawesome icons (which i use for custom post type meta data). Then, the fontawesome icons appeared. If i added the <a href> again and saved, it worked. Did same procedure for the code both in my custom post type template file aswell as my functions.php file, and now everything is working. However, not with the Vantage builtin icons that i used when the site ran on IIS, but with the downloaded fontawsome-min.css file. That's just even better though, more icons to choose from :)

Comment: Glad you fixed it! :)